# Prevent updating table using procedure in different database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, security, sql-server-2017

This is my scenario:

- Windows User Gabe has `db_owner` access of database DB1.
- Windows User Gabe has `db_reader` on database DB2.
- When the user executes `UPDATE DB2.dbo.Tbl1 SET X = 1`, they get "The UPDATE permission was denied.." as expected.
- when user executes a proc `DB1.dbo.uspUpdateTable` containing the same `UPDATE` statement above, it succeeds.

I thought this might be due to database chaining or trustworthy settings but they are not enabled.

Is this the expected behavior for `db_owner` privilege?? And is there a way to prevent this?

SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are cases where updates will be allowed via the stored stored procedure without the caller having update permissions on the table in the other database.

**Ownership chaining**

The databases involved have the `DB_CHAINING` option set or the 'cross database ownership chaining' option turned on at the server level. In the case of dbo-owned objects, the databases must also the same owner (i.e. dbo user maps to same login) to mainain an unbroken ownership chain.

**EXECUTE AS**

The stored procedure includes an `EXECUTE AS USER` specification and the user (mapped to same login) exists in the other database with update permissions. Note that the database must be `TRUSTWORTHY` in order for the `EXECUTE AS` context to be honored by other databases so this does not apply in your case.

**Module Signing**

The stored procedure is signed by a certificate and a user created from that certificate exists in the other database with permissions to update the table.

I see from your comment that 'cross database ownership chaining' was the culprit. This also implies the databases also have the same owner. I suggest you change the database owner for databases where non-sysadmin role members can create dbo-owned objects to mitigate security risk.